# Pass JavaScript var to PHP inside JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, passwords

I know this question might be duplicated. But I still couldn't find the solution yet. Let's assume I have a form look like this

```js
function validateForm(){
  var cryptedoriginalPassword = "<? echo $cryptedOriPassword; ?>";
  var password = document.forms["userForm"]["password"].value;
  
  if(password != ""){ 
    if(password == crytedoriginalPassword){
      return true;
    }else{
     alert("Password do not match!");
     return false;     
    }
  }else{
    alert("Please type your password!"); 
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="userForm" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">
<p>Old Password</p>
<input id="password" type="password" name="password" style="width: 200px;" />
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

My question, I manage to fetch password value in validateForm(), but then I need pass to php variable, so I able to check if the password is match with the original password. How can I do that?

Original password is crypted. That why I need to get the password value so I can make it crypted as well in php. And of course this happened before form is submitted!

Comment: Why would you do the check in the frontend and not the backend??? Do you realize this is not secure at all!?

Comment: because all my error message in this form at front end. I do like this so 'user' don't need to click on submit button then wait for the error appear. To me is easy validate straight away like this. That why I crypted the password. I guess if no solution I need to check at backend tho.

Comment: You are making the password accessible which is a security.... You have to do the encryption in plain JavaScript to verify it matches.... there is no way to compare the two.... Make an Ajax call or submit the form. You are just asking for trouble

Comment: where did you get encrypt the password? I mean encryption algorithm is where front or back end.js password is plain text and cryptedpassword is not same..js just validate the string not ah encryption matching.suerly this is not better approach .go with ajax call or form submit post request

Comment: I have a function in PHP that can encrypted the password, when the screen load I already fetch the 'user' information and the password as well, then run the encrypted password function and store it into variable (cryptedOriPassword).

Answer (score -1):

I think the better solution is to store PHP variable within DOM element.

Here it is, in your HTML file:

```html
<body>
  <div id="cryptedOriPassword"><?=$cryptedOriPassword?></div>
</body>
```

And in your javascript file, you can access this variable in this way:

```
function validateForm(){
    var cryptedOriPassword = document.getElementById('cryptedOriPassword');
    var password = document.forms["userForm"]["password"].value;
    if(cryptedOriPassword == password) {
        blablabla...
    }
}
```

But this can be insecure to add password judgement logic from frontend side, think this will not cause any secure problem